# Notation confusion with sigma algebra generated by a set or a class

Tags: measure-theory, notation

Consider a set $E$ and the sigma algebra generated by $C\subset\mathcal{P}(E)$. I would like to know where we can write $C\in\sigma(C)$ or $C\subset\sigma(C)$.

My thoughts were that if $C$ is a set, there is no problem to write $C\in\sigma(C)$ by definition of a sigma algebra generated by a set but the inclusion seems incorrect. Indeed, consider $E=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and

$$
\sigma(\{1\}) = \{ \emptyset, E, \{1\}, \{2,3,4\} \}
$$

it's clear that the set $\{1\}$ is in $\sigma(\{1\})$ but $1\not\in\sigma(\{1\})$ so $\{1\}$ is not included in $\sigma(\{1\})$.

However, if $C$ is a class (following the definition provided by Paul Halmos in his book on measure theory), I think that the use of $\in$ is not correct since the set itself could not be in the sigma algebra (but the elements of the set, that are also set, yes). If I consider the previous example with the class $C = \{\{1\}, \{2,4\}\}$, it seems that each element will be found in the sigma algebra generated by this class $C$, but not $C$ itself.

I would like to know if I am wrong or not and have your insights on this please.

Thank you a lot

---

Thanks to Andrew a mistake leading to a contradiction has been changed.

Comment: "it's clear that the set $\{1\}$ is not in $\sigma(\{1\})$." But it is in what you wrote.

Comment: @AndrewZhang  For a set to be included in another set (say $X$)  each element of this set need to belong to $X$, here $1$ is not in $\sigma(\{1\})$ or I misunderstand something ? Thank you.

Comment: What you wrote is the definition of being a subset

Comment: @AndrewZhang Very sorry, the « not » in the sentence you quote is a mistake. I did not realize sorry. The « not » was only for the inclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term $C$ generates a sigma algebra does only make sense if $C\subseteq\mathcal{P}(E)$. So $C$ is a set of subsets of $E$. And the sigma Algebra generated by $C$ is the smallest sigma algebra containing $C$. So this sigma algebra is again a set of subsets of $E$ with $C\subseteq\sigma(C)$. If $C\subseteq E$ then $\sigma(C)$ does not make sense.

Comment: This is right. $C$ is a collection of sets, and $\sigma(C)$ is another, typically larger, collection of sets. $\sigma(C)$ always contains *at least* the sets in $C$, along with various other sets (complements of the sets in $C$, etc). Now $C$ may happen to already be a sigma algebra, in which case $\sigma(C) = C$.

Comment: Thank you a lot for this answer. However, if we take the example I gave, I don't see how $\{1\}$ could be included in $\sigma(\{1\})$ since 1 is not included in $\sigma(\{1\})$ but only sets that include $1$ ? I think I am missing something. As for your last sentence, I am not convinced since if $C\subset E$ then $C\subset\mathcal{P}(E)$ by definition no ? So why it does not make sense to consider $\sigma(C)$ ?

Comment: It is a difference between $1$ and $\{1\}$. In your sigma algebra you only want to have subsets of $E$ so the elements of your sigma algebra are all sets by itself. $\{1\}$ is an element 0f $\sigma(\{1\})$ but $1$ is not an element. If you consider $\sigma(C)$ then this means you search for the smallest sigma algebra that contains all elements (that are subsets of $E$) of $C$. So $C$ needs to be a set of subsets of $E$ and not a subset of $E$.